# How to get Full Name of Contacts in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, abaddressbook

Now am using this code to fetch the contacts from my phone:

```
 var addressBookReff: ABAddressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil).takeRetainedValue()
    let people:NSArray = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBookReff).takeRetainedValue()
    for person in people{
        if  let name:String = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)?.takeRetainedValue() as? String {
            let numbers:ABMultiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty).takeRetainedValue()
            if let number:String = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(numbers,0)?.takeRetainedValue() as? String {
                self.arrOfDictContacts.addObject(["\(name)":"\(number)"])
            }
        }
    }
```

Here, am using `kABPersonFirstNameProperty` to get only the first name.

I want to get the full name of the contacts!!!

If I use, `kABPersonCompositeNameFormatFirstNameFirst` then am getting error as `Int is not convertible toABPropertyId`

Pardon me If this question is simple and have many answers, I could find any of them working for me as I dont want to call extra function.

So how can I get the full name and add it to the dictionary 
`arrOfDictContacts` ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In the AddressBook API, you can get the full/composite name with the following code:

```
let name = ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person).takeRetainedValue()
```

In the Contacts API (for iOS 9+), you can use this code:

```
let name: String? = CNContactFormatter.string(from: contact, style: .fullName)
```

Comment: what is the `record` here?

Comment: Updated to swift 3: `let name = CNContactFormatter.string(from: contact, style: .fullName)`

Comment: u also need to add this `CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName) as CNKeyDescriptor` in the keys of `CNContactFetchRequest`, otherwise app will crash.